JQuery JSONP Ajax call executing successfully but being reported as error
I am making a jsonp ajax call to a local service which responds with a valid javascript response. The ajax request looks like below:
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:12345",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "myFunction",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function (jqxhrInternal, message, errorThrown) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqxhrInternal));
            console.log('message: ' + message);
            console.log('errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });

And the response returned has a "application/javascript" Content-Type header with a value of:
myFunction({"key": "value"});

The script is added to the webpage automatically and the function is executed without any errors, however the ajax function is entering the error function and is telling me that myFunction was not called. I've googled for hours and tried everything, jQuery just won't detect that the function has successfully executed. The jQuery version is 3.6.1. What is the reason for this behaviour from jQuery and how can I resolve it?

You defined the jsonpCallback: "myFunction" in ajax request. So when ajax get the response, it will call myFunction with the result too. You need to write function myFunction(data){} or remove the jsonpCallback in ajax request.

Agreed with @user25009716 here, either remove jsonpCallback: "myFunction", or create a function function myFunction(data){ //...do your desired stuff here...}

What is the exact error message?

@Death-is-the-real-truth The function already exists globally, and it is successfully executed when the ajax call returns, as I can see the changes it makes on the webpage, despite that it still shows a parsererror and that myFunction was not called (which it obviously was)
